# Fancybox 3.1 transition effect between slides

Tags: fancybox-3

according to this https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/LyNXqr
transition effect between slides, can have "rotate" "fade "circular" and much more. I am already using FB 3.1

Currently in the code below i have put the transition effect to be rotate but it does not work. Pls tell the complete and exact code and where it should be placed. Because i am very new to JS, as i know only much about HTML and CSS.

```
  $.fancybox.defaults.loop = true;

                        $('[data-fancybox="project1"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true,
                        preload: '40',
                        transitionEffect : "rotate",


                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project2"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true,
                        transitionEffect : "rotate",
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project3"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project4"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project5"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project6"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project7"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project8"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project9"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference -

```
$('[data-fancybox="project2"]').fancybox({
        slideShow : {
            autoStart : true,
            transitionEffect : "rotate"
        }
    });
```

and

```
$('[data-fancybox="project2"]').fancybox({
    slideShow : {
        autoStart : true
    },
    transitionEffect : "rotate"
});
```